# How do I modify the style that VSCode's javascript formatter uses to set a line continuation indent?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working in a JavaScript code base that has a style mandating 2 space indents, with 4 spaces for statements that continue onto the next line.

For example, the following is *correctly* formatted in this style guide:

```
if (cond1()
    && cond2()
    && cond3()) {
  doSomething();
  doSomethingElse();
}
```

Notice that `doSomething()` and `&& cond3()` aren't aligned in the same column.

However, the VSCode JavaScript formatter, by default, formats as this:

```
if (cond1()
  && cond2()
  && cond3()) {
  doSomething();
  doSomethingElse();
}
```

Does the VS Code JavaScript formatter have settings that control this? Otherwise, is there a "standard" extension that replaces the built-in JavaScript formatter that supports this style?

Answer (score -1):

I don't have that behaviour but I use the extension Prettier - Code formatter. Hope that can help you

Comment: Does the Prettier formatter have a setting for indenting a statement broken onto two lines more? I couldn't find that setting.